# How does the bootstrap site know which part of the page you are on?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started using bootstrap recently, and I saw  that this page: [components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) highlighted which section of the page you were on in the sidebar. How do they do this?

Comment: they look at what's on the top of the visible viewport.

Comment: It's done with one of the JavaScript plugins -- [ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with scrollspy, a script which is now included in the bootstrap.js file.

All the script does is watch where you are on the page based on where you place an id on a containing tag.

You can also enable scrollspy for a specific element using:

```
$('body').scrollspy();
```

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/adamp/LWWCb/3/